# ICollection does not contain a definition for Any

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I'm writing code using eager loading to load the related data from `Assigned` using the `Include` method. I'm trying to get the value for `IsAvailable`, as to access the data from `Assigned` and check if there is a record which have the value of `ReturnDate` is equal to null. I keep on getting an error saying

> ICollection does not contain a definition for Any

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var item = db.Item.Include(h => h.Assigned).Select(b => new ItemViewModel
        {
            ItemID = b.ItemID,
            ItemName = b.ItemName,
            Category = b.Category,
            Description = b.Description,
            Model = b.Model,
            IsAvailable = !b.Assigned.Any(h => h.ReturnDate == null)
        }).ToList();

        return View(item);
    }
```

ItemViewModel

```
public class ItemViewModel
{

    public int ItemID { get; set;}
    [Display(Name = "Item")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category is required")]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

Item class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections;

    namespace Inventoryproto3.Models
    {
        public class Item
        {
    
            public int ItemID { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter a title"),Display(Name ="Item")]
            public string ItemName { get; set;}
            [Required(ErrorMessage ="Category is required")]
            public string Category { get; set;}
            public string Model { get; set;}
            public string Description{get; set;}
    
            public ICollection Assigned { get; set; }
    
    
        }
    }
```

> 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no accessible extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh8zg.png)

Comment: Post your `Item` entity class.

Comment: Post the _exact_ error message. And are you `using System.Linq;` ?

Comment: Did you include System.Linq? What is the type of `b.Assigned`?

Comment: I did incluse system.linq , B.assigned is an Icollection property

Comment: You need to define your property as a *generic* `ICollection` in order to use LINQ functionality. For example: `ICollection<Assigned>`.

Comment: @haim770  Thank you alot.idk how i missed that. It worked

Answer (score 0):

Every `Item` has a property `Assigned`, which is of type `ICollection`.

If you look at the definition of [Queryable.Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Queryable_Any__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Boolean___) you'll find:

```
public static bool Any<TSource> (this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
       Expression<Func<TSource,bool>> predicate);
```

Therefore property `Assigned` should implement `ICollection<TSource>` where TSource is the actual type you expect to find in your collection.

The proper solution would be to change the type of property `Assigned`, such that you know that the collection only contains items of the type you expect. Alas you chose to give us a lot of unimportant information, but you forgot to mention the class of items in `Assigned`, so let's assume it's of type `MyClass`.

```
class MyClass
{
    public Datetime ReturnDate {get; set;}
    ...
}

class Item
{
     ...
     public ICollection<MyClass> Assigned {get; set;}
}
```

This will solve your problem: `Any(...)` works, and you are certain that people can only put `MyClass` objects in the collection.

If you don't want to limit your collection to MyClass objects, you can at least limit yourself to classes with property `ReturnDate`:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    public Datetime ReturnDate {get; set;}
}

class Item
{
     ...
     public ICollection<IMyInterface> Assigned {get; set;}
}
```

If you really want that people can add other things than `MyClass` objects in the collection, something I strongly advise against, you'll have to specify what you want:

- Ignore items in the collection that are not MyClass objects? Use `OfType`
- Just hope that no one ever put something else in the collection? Use `Cast`, but then again: why not prevent that someone puts an incorrect object in the class, and define `ICollection<MyClass>`?

`OfType` probably does not works `AsQueryable`, in that case you should move the data to your local process using `AsEnumerable`. A third reason to use a correct type for ICollection right.

```
IsAvailable = !b.Assigned.OfType<MyClass>().Any(h => h.ReturnDate == null);
IsAvailable = !b.Assigned.Cast<MyClass>().Any(h => h.ReturnDate == null);
```

The first one will ignore items of your collection with other types. The latter one will throw an exception if there is another type in your collection (fourth reason to make it an `ICollection<MyClass>`